# Set up a domain name for Google app maker

Tags: dns, google-app-maker, google-workspace

How do we set up a domain name for the Google App Maker?
I've got a domain name from google and working on an app maker project.

*I was not able to find any help in Google App Maker documentation, Stackoverflow or anywhere on the internet.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Maker apps are only available to users in your G Suite organization. You can't share apps with external users. You cannot use your custom domain name for App Maker apps.

There is a feature request for this ability: [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63382989).

If you understand how to buid a website you could create a custom URL with your domain name that when hit redirects the user to the actual URL. This is very easy to do and only takes a line of code. This could also be configured in the Apache webserver or just about all webservers.

Example:

User goes to your website: https://www.example.com/my-url

Your website redirects `my-url` to the App Maker URL. I would use a 301 for a permanent redirect or a 307 for a temporary redirect.